# Base address of the Web API URL in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

In c# Web API, I need to access the base address of the Web API URL.

I tried using

```
string applicationpath =  HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
```

but that did not work.

I used the `IWebHostEnvironment`, even it did not have enough information about it.

How do I access the url?

Comment: In a controller action both the context and request are accessible as properties. Have you tried `this.Request.PathBase`, `this.Request.GetEncodedUrl()` or `this.Request.GetDisplayUrl()`?  `HttpContext.Current` doesn't exist in ASP.NET Core. The HttpContext is no longer a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url
```

Comment: HttpContext doesn't have a `Current` property in ASP.NET Core

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are right. My bad, sorry.